# oci_bind_array_by_name only works on arrays with numeric indices, and not on associative arrays php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, associative-array, oracle-call-interface

I am trying to send associative array as a parameter to oracle procedure but it is giving me  below error

> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong
>   number or types of arguments in call to 'IOBIND' ORA-06550

But Working well with the numeric indexed array.

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

```
$create = "CREATE TABLE bind_example(name VARCHAR(20))";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $create);

oci_execute($stid);

$create_pkg = "

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ARRAYBINDPKG1 AS

TYPE ARRTYPE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(20) INDEX BY VARCHAR(20);

PROCEDURE iobind(c1 IN ARRTYPE);

END ARRAYBINDPKG1;";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $create_pkg);

oci_execute($stid);

$create_pkg_body = "

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ARRAYBINDPKG1 AS

PROCEDURE iobind(c1 IN ARRTYPE) IS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO bind_example VALUES (c1('one'));

END iobind;

END ARRAYBINDPKG1;";

$stid = oci_parse($conn, $create_pkg_body);

oci_execute($stid);

$stid = oci_parse($conn, "BEGIN arraybindpkg1.iobind(:c1); END;");

$array = array("one" => 'Test1', "two" => 'Test2', "three" => 'Test3');

oci_bind_array_by_name($stid, ":c1", $array, 3, -1, SQLT_CHR);

oci_execute($stid);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Check the [OCI8 manual](https://www.php.net/manual/book.oci8.php)  and [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

Comment: Thankyou @ChristopherJones for your comment.
I find examples for numerical array in OCI8 manual and in the ug-php-oracle book not for an associative array.